# R - Finding Values in a Row based on Criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset that has two basic conditions, and I'm trying to match these values based on their position in the data frame.  Here's an example:

```
Row Cond  Y
1   n   350
2   n   354
3   t   375
4   n   300
5   n   157
6   t   810
7   n   214
8   n   243
9   n   345
10  n   216
11  n   198
12  t   870
```

I'd like to match each value of "n" with a nearby value of "t" (i.e., within 5 rows of one another).  Then, I'd like to subtract the value of "n" from "t".  In the example above, our row 1 would be matched with row 3, and we'd come out with a value of 25 (375 - 350).  If the row is equidistant between two "t" rows, I'd like to default to the earlier "t" row, if possible.  Ideally, I'd create a new vector with these difference scores, where appropriate, so that an "NA" or "0" appears for rows with a "t" condition.  So this would look like:

```
Result
25
21
NA
75
653
NA
596
567
465
654
672
NA
```

Is there a way to implement this in R?  I've tried a few subsets based on criteria (e.g, "<" or "=="), but I'm wondering if I'm approach it in the wrong way!  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: So what happens when n is the same distance between two t's line 8 for example). It's nice that you provided sample data, but it would also be helpful if shared what the desired result for this sample data would be so we can test possible solutions.

Comment: How will your desired output look like?

Comment: Updated with a prospective output and a few clarifications.  Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: And what happens when there is no `t` within 3 rows from `n`?

Comment: If there is no "t" within X rows, I'd like to return an "NA" if possible.

Comment: Try this `sapply(X = 1:nrow(df), FUN = function(i) ifelse(df[i,"Cond"]=="t", NA, df[(j<-which(df[,"Cond"]=="t"))[which.min(abs(i-j))], "Y"]-as.numeric(df[i,"Y"])))`. df used `df = structure(list(Row = 1:12, Cond = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("n", "t"), class = "factor"), 
    Y = c(350L, 354L, 375L, 300L, 157L, 810L, 214L, 243L, 345L, 
    216L, 198L, 870L)), .Names = c("Row", "Cond", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getclosest <- function(df, i) {
   if (as.character(df$Cond[[i]]) == "t") {
      return (NA)
   } else {
      # df$Y[i]
      below <- NA
      above <- NA
      aj <- NA
      bj <- NA
      for (j in 1:5) {
          pos <- i - j
          if (pos < 1) break
          if (df$Cond[pos] == "t") {
            below <- df$Y[pos]
            bj <- j
            break
          }
      }
      for (j in 1:5) {
        pos <- i + j
        if (pos > nrow(df)) break 
        if (df$Cond[pos] == "t") {
           above <- df$Y[pos]
           aj <- j
           break
        }
      }
      temp = NA
      tempb = NA
      if (is.na(above) && is.na(below)) {
          return(NA)
      }
      if (!is.na(below) && !is.na(above)) {

        if (aj  < bj) {
           return(abs(above - df$Y[i]))
        } else {
           return(abs(below - df$Y[i]))
        }
      }
      if (!is.na(below)) {
        tempb <- abs(below - df$Y[i])
        return (tempb)
      }
      if (!is.na(above)) { 
         tempa <- abs(above - df$Y[i])
         return(tempa)
      }

    return (NA)
   }
}

df <- data.frame(Cond=c('n', 'n', 't','n','n','t','n','n','n','n','n','t'), Y=c(350,354,375,300,157,810,214,243,345,216,198,870))

v <- c() # length=nrow(df))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { 
   v[i] <- getclosest(df, i)
}
```

Comment: Scott, this works perfectly!  Thank you so much for your time and insights!